# Mongoose, populate where an ID is specific to a project reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I m trying to populate a mongoose model where I only want the returned items to be the ones that are matched with an ID.

Edit update: In the User model below, I need to first find the correct user by id, then for the `task` property, I need to populate it where the `projectID` matches `req.params.ID`. How can I only populate the tasks where the `projectID` matches the `req.params.ID`. I have included my full User model as well as the Task model

//User Schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "First Name is Required"
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: "Username is Required"
  },
  skills: {
    type: String,
    trim : true
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String
  },
  SQLid: {
    type: Number
  },
  userCreated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  lastUpdated: { 
    type: Date
  },
  adminTeams: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Team"
  }],
  team: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Team"
  }],
  task: [{
    projectID: {
      type: String
    },
    theTask: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Task" 
    }
  }]
});
```

//Task Schema

```
var TodoSchema = new Schema({
  task: {
    type: String
  }
});
```

How can I only get the `task` populated where the projectID is equal to a specific ID. I tried

```
User.findById({ "_id": req.params.id }).populate({ path: 'task', match: {projectID: req.params.pID}, select: 'theTask' })
  .exec(function(err, docs){
    console.log("POPULATE TASKS DOCS", docs)
```

But this is showing that the docs is empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$elemMatch` ,it will give you all those docs which matches your projectId and populate your task document .
 So the query would be -

```
var query={
           task:{
                     $elemMatch:{
                            projectId: req.params.id
                                 }  
                    }
           }

User.find(query)
.populate('theTask')
.select('theTask')  // use for getting selective data from document
.exec(function(){}) //your callback fuction
```

Hope I answer your question.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried this out but it returns the _id of the task and proeject instead of the actual task. I have included my full User model and Task model

Answer (score 0):

In your task schma you have kept the type of the task type as `string` and in your user schema the theTask have the refrence of the task and task its Self is just a `string` . Thats why it is not being populated ..

So change the task schema to (Keep it simple)-

```
var Task= new Schema({
  name :string
     });
```

Populate need refrence Id to get the whole document